# Importing a function from a different file in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**Background:**

I've created a Screens.js file which contains each separate screen as a function. Then I'm calling the screens from App.js.

**What I have tried**

This is a mockup of what I have in the Screens.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, Button, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

export const LoginScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text> This is a Login Screen </Text> 
            <Button
                title="Go to Home"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')} 
            />
        </View>
    )
}

export const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text> This is a Home Screen </Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

And this is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

import { LoginScreen, HomeScreen } from './app/Screens.js';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={ LoginScreen } />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={ HomeScreen } />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**Problem**

When I try and run the app in expo, I get the following error message: "Invariant Violation: Module RCTEventEmitter is not a registered callable Module (calling recieveTouches)" I have absolutely no idea what any of this means, I don't even know what an RCTEventEmitter or recieveTouches actually is.

**Question**

Is this the correct method to import a function from a separate file? Is there any better way? Maybe the problem isn't even related to the calling of the functions? (Note: I've tried other methods in the past but they all failed, so it probably is an export-import issue.)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do that.

try this

```
exports.default = {
LoginScreen : ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text> This is a Login Screen </Text> 
            <Button
                title="Go to Home"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')} 
            />
        </View>
    )
},


HomeScreen : ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text> This is a Home Screen </Text>
        </View>
    )
}

}
```

this is a hint, not exact code.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for accepting as answer.  This is so quick man !  got my answer approved within seconds.

Comment: No problem, I was just browsing other people's questions and saw your answer, as soon as I knew you were new here I thought I might aswell welcome you properly :) Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Just one thing, whenever you answer a question try to provide an explanation. Some guy in the top 1% of users kept commenting on my posts to tell me that good answers don't only show the correct way to do something, but they also teach how that is done. Your answer helped me a lot, but for someone else it'd be great if you could help others learn!